# Why can I no longer run git command (error: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5...)

Tags: git, macos

I haven't changed anything on my machine. I run this command everytime I make changes to my code.

```
git push thing-staging beta-staging:master
```

The response I get is:

*no matching mac found: client hmac-md5....fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly*

Anyone have any suggestions on why this no longer works or how to find out what is exactly going on?

Comment: It appears that your local `ssh` is incompatible with the ssh server used on the git repository to which you are pushing. Has either you local system or the remote system had a recent update?

Comment: I updated my Mac to OSX 10.12. So how do I change my local ssh and change it to what?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your local ssh is incompatible with the ssh server used on the git repository to which you are pushing. It sounds like the server is running an older version of the ssh server while your newer client has dropped default support for the `hmac-md5` algorithm (because that algorithm is now considered insecure).

You can modify the MAC algorithms used by `ssh` with the `MACs` configuration option in your `~/.ssh/config` file.  According to the [ssh_config man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#MACs), the default list of enabled MACs is:

```
umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com, 
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, 
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, 
umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com, 
hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
```

The above may be version dependent.  You would need to add hmac-md5 to this list, so you would add to your `~/.ssh/config` something like:

```
MACs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
```

This would apply the configuration to *all* your ssh connections; you could also use a `Match` directive to apply this only to the server hosting your remote git repository.  See the `ssh_config` man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading my mac after not using it for about 6 months.  I deleted my id_rsa and is_rsa.pub and regenerated them with ssh-keygen -t rsa

This was kind of a pain as my old ssh key was in a bunch of remote servers that I connect to but if you do give this a try just remember to add your new ssh key to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opposite problem of that solved by [René Vogt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528593/ren%c3%a9-vogt) answer, this may help. I'm having to use coLinux under Windows 7 again after somehow borking my xWindows on my Debian 12 partition and *none* of the MACs on Debian squeeze (version 6) are compatible with github's.

In ~/.bash_aliases, I have:

```
osversion=$(uname -r)
if [ "${osversion%%-*}" = "2.6.33.7" ]; then
    alias ssh="ssh -F $HOME/.ssh/squeeze"
    alias scp="scp -F $HOME/.ssh/squeeze"
    export GIT_SSH=$HOME/bin/ssh.squeeze
fi
```

In ~/bin/ssh.squeeze:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -F $HOME/.ssh/squeeze -T dedicated ssh $*
```

In ~/.ssh/squeeze:

```
Host *
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
```

The `dedicated` host is defined in /etc/hosts, and can be any VPS or dedicated server with a more modern OS.